# How to load a resource using a subdomain in CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Is it possible to load a resource using a subdomain in CanCan?

The `load_resource` and `load_and_authorize_resource` methods are an alias to this:

```
def load
    @foo = Resource.find(params[:id])
end
```

In my case, I need to load the resource based on a subdomain. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the load_resource to use the subdomain instead and than just call authorize_resource on it

Not sure how you code is structured, but something along this lines should work

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_by_subdomain
  load_and_authorize_resource

  private

  def find_by_subdomain
    @book = Model.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
  end
end
```

Comment: call authorize_resource on what exactly? The instance of the resource?

Comment: I've included a basic example, also take a look at https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-Controller-Actions